# How to do not reuse same data from DB when rendering route NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

So I have this route:

```
app.get('/arena', (req, res) => {
                User.findById(req.session.userId).then((user) => {
                    BoughtItem.find({username: user.username}).then((userItems) => {
                BoughtItem.find().sort('-createdAt').limit(20).then((liveitems) => {
                    Fight.find().sort('-createdAt').limit(26).then((fights) => {
                        LostFight.find().sort('-createdAt').limit(50).then((lostFights) => {
                            Message.find().sort('-createdAt').limit(20).then((messages) => {    
                res.render(__dirname + '/views/arena/index', {user, users, userItems, messages, liveitems, fights, lostFights});
            });
          });
        });
       });
      });
    });
   });
```

Now what I wanna to do is when some error occurs I want to do this:

```
`return res.render(__dirname + '/views/arena/index', {errMsg: 'Some error message'});`
```

But is there a way to render `arena` again like this without reusing all code from the above to find `user` `BoughtItem` etc. ?

Comment: You can either add error callback or use try catch approach.

Comment: @Ved I didn't metioned but i want to `return` that route in another route when error occurs.